# how to change angualar.module constant config fields?

Tags: angularjs

I want to change the value for `dashboardApi` from `http://devdashboard.company.com/'` to `../api`(relative path to a folder which is onelevel up),I tried as `../api` but doesn't work,how to fix it?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('configuration', [])
    .constant('config', {
        dashboardApi : 'http://devdashboard.company.com/',
        authApi: 'http://urlink.company.com/',
        debug: false,
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        userid: '',
        employeeid: '',
        qGroups: [""],
        role : '',
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want to change it, you can inject `config` dependency inside desired `component` of your main angular module.

```
//make sure configuration module have been injected in main app module.
angular.module('app', ['configuration']);

//here I took an example of config block of your application.
//because generally such setting should be set at configuration time of app.
//the same inject you can do it other component as well, like controller, directive, factory, etc.
angular.module('app').config(['config', function(config){
   config.dashboardApi = '../api.'
})
```